# Why is this simple cronjob not running and how do I check the relevant log files?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, cron, crontab

I have an 'R' script that I wish to run at 00:30 every day, that is, 12:30 AM everyday. The script itself is located in `~/Desktop/foldername/runme.r` and `which Rscript` tells me that the exact path to binary `Rscript` is `/usr/bin/Rscript`. So I make the following crontab entry:

```
crontab -e
54 13 * * * /usr/bin/Rscript ~/Desktop/foldername/runme.r
```

Time right now is 13:52 of course. And I wait 5 minutes to see if a CSV file is created in my home folder. Since the R script runme.r has instructions to process some data and then create a CSV file in the home folder.

But no luck. At 13:54, no CSV file is created in my home folder. Please note that when I manually run this script (without using cron), it *does* create a CSV in my home folder. So I know there's nothing wrong with my script. So why is the cronjob not running as intended and what can I do to correct it or how do I check log files for additional sources of information?

EDIT: NEW OBSERVATION

If I change the line to `* * * * * /usr/bin/Rscript /home/username/Desktop/foldername/runme.r` instead of specifying the exact time, it does create the right CSV file in the right location. So `* * * * *` works and `54 13 * * *` doesn't. Why?

Comment: try to use absolute path instead of ~

Comment: That's what I just thought of as well, and so I tried absolute paths everywhere, even in my R script and cronjob: `/home/username/Desktop/...` but that didn't work either. I wonder if I have to restart cron process or reboot or something?

Comment: I'd start with something simple to test that cron is working for you at all.  Something like /usr/bin/touch /tmp/crontest as your command.  That will at least let you know that cron is doing the right thing and the problem is with getting it run your Rscript.

Comment: Is crond running? What happens if you comment that line out and configure "* * * * * /bin/date >> /tmp/test.me" instead

Comment: @davidgo crond is running according to `ps -e | grep cron`. I even restarted it using `service crond restart`. But no good. Addtionally, I added that `test.me` line to 'crontab -e' and I can see the `test.me` file in the tmp folder ! So cron is running fine

Comment: Added a new observation in the question above.

Comment: Is this a local system? cron might be running in a different timezone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289751/cron-job-in-a-different-timezone

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out after the last observation I made regarding time. This is going to make me look silly, but I had gotten the time wrong. I'm testing this cronjob in a virtual machine that has a time different from my host machine. I was scheduling the job in the virtual machine, and looking at the time on my host machine. Both times being different meant that script didn't execute on the time I expected it too.